# Minimum number of balanced partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

For any multiset $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2n}$ of positive real numbers, a partition into two nonempty subsets $(A,B)$ is called "balanced" if $\text{sum}(A)\geq\text{sum}(B)-\max(B)$ and $\text{sum}(B)\geq\text{sum}(A)-\max(A)$.

What is the minimum number of balanced partitions, in terms of $n$?

The question received [no answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917666/minimum-number-of-balanced-partitions) on Math.SE after four months.

Comment: I suspect the minimum occurs when all the x's are the same. Then the answer is 2n choose n, which is likely the best as for many multisets one can have many partitions of differing sizes.  Gerhard "Halfway Towards Having A Proof" Paseman, 2019.01.28.

Comment: What it is the origin and background of this question?

Comment: I answered on the math.SE question - I think Harper's vertex isoperimetric inequality does the job.